# php session error to logout

Tags: php, mysql, session

My login is working, since its redirecting me to the index.php.
But after I click on the login button it goes to the index.php, and the session is not logged in. It's supposed to state "Hello $username", but it still states "Login again" instead of Logout.

index.php code:

```
<?php
        session_start();    
        if( !empty($_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['username'])){
            echo 'Olá ' . $_SESSION['username'];
            echo '<a href="logout.php"><br/>Logout</a>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<a href="login.php" class="hiper">Fazer Login</a>';
            echo '<a href="criarconta.php" class="hiper"><br/>Criar Conta</a><br/>';
        }
      ?>
```

login.php code:

```
<?php

    if(!empty($_POST)){
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        require_once 'Validate.php';
        $flag_error = false;
        $errors = array ('username' => array (false,'username incorrecto.'),'password' => array (false,'Password tem de conter pelo menos 8 caracteres.'));


    /*if(!checkusername($username)){
        $errors['username'][0] = true;
        $flag_error=true;

    }

    if(!Valid_Pass($password)){
        $errors['password'][0]=true;
        $flag_error=true;

    }*/

    if(!$flag_error){

        require_once 'ligacao.php';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM utilizadores` WHERE 'username' = '$username' AND 'password' = '$password'";
        $verificar=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

        if (mysql_num_rows($verificar)==true){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header('Location: index.php');
            }else{
            echo '<font color="red"> Esta conta não existe. </font></a>';   
        }

    }   
}
?>
```

I know login works because it redirects to "header('Location: index.php');", but the session stay logged in. What could it be?

Comment: It looks like you are missing a quotations mark on your query, right before the name of your table. Also, you might want to consider: 1) Using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of *mysql* for PHP, and 2) an escaping function for protecting against SQL injection (i.e. `mysqli::real_escape_string`)

Comment: offtopic, try and be more consistent with you code formatting, it's all over the place right now. Makes it much easier to read if it's consistent.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `session_start()` on every page that uses the session, so add it to the top of login.php.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start();`

This starts the session and you should use it in every file who you need to user Login for visit it.

```
 $_SESSION['color']='red'; 
 $_SESSION['size']='small'; 
 $_SESSION['shape']='round';
```

This sets variables in the session

```
 session_unset();
```

Remove all session variables

```
 session_destroy();
```

Destroy the session